# mongodb shell require a js function from another file

Tags: mongodb, spidermonkey, mongodb-shell

I have two Mongodb shell scripts written in js.
Both are sharing some code between them. Is it possible to extract that code to another file and to import it from there? And how?

I have been trying with `require / import` but that obviously not working, also tried with `load()` but no success.

I know it is using the **SpiderMonkey** js engine, but no idea if it is possible.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#execute-a-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  The solution is .mongorc.js file at your home directory.

Check documentation [here!](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#.mongorc.js-file)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit or give an example?

Comment: Whatever code you put in .mongorc.js -file (in your home directory) it is loaded when you start mongo.  So, you extract that code (what is shared) as a function/procedure and put it there. All scripts (.js) can use it.

Comment: So it is globally defined? like the `db` variable?

Comment: Not... Really. That file can have one or more function(s) and/or procedure(s) what you can use/call inside mongo - when you run it as a command tool or when you run some other .js code with it.